# Progress monitoring for Web Services

Tags: java, php, web-services, glassfish, java-ee-7

Iam currently exploring the new world of web services in order to exploit them for an application that I build during my PhD.

A brief description of the architecture:

A PHP front end acquires a link from the user and through a SoapClient triggers a data analysis process that is going to be held in the web service.

The web service (Java EE, Glassfish) will carry out the analysis BUT usually this process is not instantaneous. Consequently  I am searcing for a method-pattern-tool that will allow the web service to provide progress feedback back to the PHP frontend

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Use either PHP or Java for both ends whatever you are more comfortable with.  Soap is probably an unnecessary complication. Your service just needs to report using standard a http body in a data format you can easily handle - the state at the end of it's run and be capable of processing multiple simultaneous requests. this is a bog standard 'webservice' pattern.  Your client will need to be able to receive information on the order of requests so that it can discard ones older than those it already has.  Please provide concrete examples of what you have tried, to obtain more detailed responses.

Comment: Yes I agree that an easy solution will be to use java or PHP on both ends but it is not possible. The front end is based on an excellent jQuery template that provides beautiful graphs and reports. The backend is a java tool that is being built for the last 3 years. The only acceptable method that I found to make those two ends communicate is to transform my java tool into a webservice. I personally believe that this is a very good solution.

Comment: JQuery being JavaScript, has nothing to do with either PHP or Java, for the client side, you may only actually NEED static HTML pages to put it on, but that is an aside host it how you will. Look up asynchronous calls using AJAX within the JQuery framework to provide the client - server interactions you need I would suggest JSON as a transfer format but use whatever you want. You need to wrap your existing tool in a Servlet or similar frameworks that may help include Restlet, restEASY, Spring amongst many.  Make it as simple as you can.